# Flip an UIImageView horizontal on tap will result in "reversed" gesture recognizer and only works 1x

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer

I implemented giphy stickers like instagram in my camera app.

I want to flip a sticker horizontally on tap with this code:

```
@objc func tapGesture(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let gestureView = gesture.view else { return }
    gestureView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
}
```

1: This works only one time. It can not be reversed flipped.

2: I have added several gesture recognizer. When I flip the image, the gestures are also reversed (rotating in the different direction, etc)

**What is the best way to flip and reflip the image, and keep the original gesture recognizer behavior?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,  I think your code works as implemented.

1. If you set a transform to (-1|1), e.g. you flip the x-axis, then this flipping will be applied to the "original" coordinate system. In other words, you do not apply a transform to the existing transform matrix, (e.g. flip and flip again), but just modify the original matrix (which is the identity matrix).
   What you might want is:

```
    gestureView.transform = gestureView.transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y:1)
```

2. If you try to rotate a view clockwise, but this view is *flipped*, then you see the rotation from behind, e.g. it *appears* as if the rotation was anti-clockwise. The gesture recognizer still works as expected.